# find url to connect to given wsdl

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm not very comfortable with SOAP and I'm trying to connect to a web service. I have the below wsdl. I'm using the `suds` python SOAP library. Which url am I supposed to use? Is there a way to tell?

I've tried to following using the suds client

```
from suds.client import Client
url = "http://tko.fni.com/application/request.xsd"
client = Client(url)
```

I've tried the above with all `tko.fni.com` endpoints from below but I might be missing something. Is this even the correct approach? I need to open a session with the client and then I can post requests to that client with an XML body?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://tko.fni.com/application.wsdl" 
    xmlns:request="http://tko.fni.com/application/request.xsd" 
    xmlns:response="http://tko.fni.com/application/response.xsd"
    xmlns:transaction="http://tko.fni.com/application/transaction.xsd"
    targetNamespace="http://tko.fni.com/application.wsdl">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
            <xs:import namespace="http://tko.fni.com/application/request.xsd" schemaLocation="application_request.xsd"/>
            <xs:import namespace="http://tko.fni.com/application/response.xsd" schemaLocation="application_response.xsd"/>
            <xs:import namespace="http://tko.fni.com/application/transaction.xsd" schemaLocation="transaction_control.xsd"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="submitApplicationRequestMsg">
        <wsdl:part element="request:REQUEST" name="applicationData"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="submitApplicationResponseMsg">
        <wsdl:part element="response:ApplicationResponse" name="applicationResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="ApplicationPortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="submitApplication">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:submitApplicationRequestMsg"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:submitApplicationResponseMsg"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="ApplicationSoapBinding" type="tns:ApplicationPortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="submitApplication">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://tko.fni.com/application/submitApplication"/>
            <wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding> 
    <wsdl:service name="ApplicationService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:ApplicationSoapBinding" name="ApplicationPort">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:80/ApplicationService/services/ApplicationPort"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: What is the URL of this WSDL file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`url` should be an address of WSDL itself ([documentation](https://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.client.Client-class.html#__init__))

WSDL files are used for describing an interface of web-service, that's why it makes sense to use it for creating a client.

Comment: I was sent this file and an example request. So the url I need is the one that returns this file essentially? I could test it by hosting this file as well? That would probably take a not small amount of effort to produce the correct response

Comment: You may try to use file path instead of URL, though documentation says nothing about such option.

Comment: yeh I tried using a file path and it's trying to make an http request :/